# PWA manifest start_url as current_url

Tags: javascript, json, url, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I have a Progreesive web app(PWA). In that i have a `manifest.json`. I want to set the manifest's `start_url` as Current url. Is there any way to set `start_url` to the current url, when installing the app?

Note:- In my PWA i every user gets a unique url to their account. So when they install the PWA, the `start_url` should be their `current_url` (ex: https://example.com/user/id=abc1322112 )

I tried to change the manifest using script.js. nothing works.

Comment: You can't dynamically change the manifest on the client side, but you could set the `start_url` to a "fake" url like `/user/me`, and redirect that to the correct `/user/id=...` in the service worker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is every time i install the app, when i open it it goes to the manifest's start url. will your answer solve this?

Comment: Yes, the end result will be that it goes to a different URL. I'll post an answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the URL in the manifest, but you can set it to a fake URL that the service worker will redirect.

Manifest:

```json
{
  "start_url": "/user/me"
}
```

Service worker:

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (url.pathname === "/user/me") {
    const userId = /* get user id here */;
    const newUrl = `/user/id=${userId}`;
    // Redirect to the correct url
    const response = new Response(null, { status: 302, headers: { Location: newUrl } });
  } else {
    // In all other cases, just fetch from the network
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
  }
});
```

Comment: it still goes to the manifest's pathname and does not redirect to the service worker's path name

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
const manifest = {
  name: 'My App',
  short_name: 'My App',
  display: 'standalone',
  theme_color: '#ffffff',
  background_color: '#ffffff',
  icons: [
    { src: `${window.location.origin}/icon-192x192.png`, sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
  ],
  start_url: window.location.href
};
const link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'manifest';
link.href = `data:application/json;base64,${btoa(JSON.stringify(manifest))}`;
document.head.appendChild(link);
</script>
```

if anyone needed, this script works.

delete your manifest.json and put this scipt inside your JS or html.
replace your icon with "icon-192x192.png"